# change color on mouse move using rgb to get the color spectrum

Tags: jquery, rgb

I found a great code here that changes a color on mousemove using rgb.

Any ideas on how to adapt this so I can get the full color range starting with red on the left to orange, yellow, green, blue, purple on the right?

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/WV8jX/

Code currently is:

```
var $win = $(window),
w = 0,h = 0,
rgb = [],
getWidth = function() {
    w = $win.width();
    h = $win.height();
};

$win.resize(getWidth).mousemove(function(e) {


rgb = [
    Math.round(e.pageX/w * 255),
    Math.round(e.pageY/h * 255),
    150
];

$(document.body).css('background','rgb('+rgb.join(',')+')');

}).resize();
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we don't modify working code.  New feature development is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: You may want to use HSL colour model (instead of RGB): you will find a lot of methods in this site. To get colour spectrum from hew can be more tricky (different "distance" of colours), but such precision is probably not what you want. And purple is a pure colour, but not a spectral colour (like all the "lines of purples"), so this is my pedantry.